# Justify text in the Algorithm environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, algorithms

I'm using `algorithm` environment and I can't fix the text alignment (i want to justify text).

Here is a screenshoot for reference.

And the code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\selectlanguage{spanish} 
\usepackage[spanish,onelanguage,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsfonts}   % Para fuentes no comunes
\usepackage{amssymb}  % Para simbolos no comunes
\usepackage{amsmath}   % Algunas cosas matematicas
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage[]{units}
%Funciones
\def\sign{\mathop{\mbox{\normalfont sign}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\evf}[2]{\mathop{\big|_{#1}^{#2}\big.}\limits}
\newcommand{\bez}{\mathop{\mathbbm{b}}}
\newcommand{\ba}[1]{\overline{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ti}[1]{\tilde{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\h}[1]{\hat{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\entera}[1]{\left[\!\left[{#1}\right]\!\right]}
\newcommand{\encima}[1]{\overline{\;#1}}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\mid {#1}\mid}
\newcommand{\norma}[1]{\parallel {#1} \parallel}
\newcommand{\mbf}[1]{\mathbf{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\area}{\mathfrak{A}}
\newcommand{\parentesis}[1]{\left({#1}\right)}
\newcommand{\corchetes}[1]{\left[{#1}\right]}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[h!] 
\caption{Esquema MOSN de integraci\'on trapezoidal en tiempo.}
\label{AlgoTrapezoidal}
\SetAlgoLined
\vspace{0.3cm}
\KwData{Las velocidades en los NFD $\corchetes{v^{\pm}_{x}}^{t_{0}}_{i}$ son conocidas de c\'aculos previos.}\vspace{0.3cm} 
\KwResult{Integraci\'on temporal del sistema Velocidad--Estado.}
\vspace{0.3cm}
%Paso 1
      \textbf{Paso 1}: Calcule $\corchetes{u^{\pm}_{x}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i}$ y $\corchetes{u^{*}_{z}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i+\nicefrac{1}{2}}$. Usando las velocidades en los NFD y condiciones iniciales, se obtiene la integraci\'on centrada $\corchetes{u^{\pm}_{x}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i} = \corchetes{u^{\pm}_{x}}^{t_{0}-\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i} + \Delta t \corchetes{v^{\pm}_{x}}^{t_{0}}_{i}$. Luego, calcule $\corchetes{u^{*}_{z}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i + \nicefrac{1}{2}}$ de la condici\'on de continuidad de $\tau_{zz}$ en el plano de falla. Esto es, sustituir la anterior aproximaci\'on de $\corchetes{\frac{\partial u^{\pm}_{x}}{\partial x}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i+\nicefrac{1}{2}}$ y la estimada de $\corchetes{\frac{\partial u^{\pm}_{z}}{\partial z}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i+\nicefrac{1}{2}}$ (usando est\'eciles en una direcci\'on de la matriz $\boldsymbol G$) en esta condici\'on de continuidad para obtener $\corchetes{u^{*}_{z}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i+\nicefrac{1}{2}}$.\

\vspace{0.3cm}
%Paso 2      
      \textbf{Paso 2}: Obtener los esfuerzos $\corchetes{\tau^{\pm}_{xx}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i+\nicefrac{1}{2}}$ y $\corchetes{\tau^{\pm}_{zz}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i+\nicefrac{1}{2}}$ introduciendo $\corchetes{\frac{\partial u^{\pm}_{x}}{\partial x}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i+\nicefrac{1}{2}}$ y $\corchetes{\frac{\partial u^{\pm}_{z}}{\partial z}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i+\nicefrac{1}{2}}$ en la Ley de Hooke (ecuaciones~\ref{Hooke1}--\ref{Hooke3}), diferenciados para obtener el gradiente del esfuerzo en los NFD $\corchetes{\frac{\partial \tau^{\pm}_{xx}}{\partial x}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i}$, y usados en la ecuaic\'on~\eqref{Rest} para obtener $\corchetes{R^{\pm}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i}$.\

\vspace{0.3cm}
%Paso 3
      \textbf{Paso 3}: Con la velocidad y la variable de estado centro--distribu\'idas en tiempo como en la Figura~\eqref{IntTrapezoidal}, integre las ecuaciones de evoluci\'on de la variable de estado \eqref{feq}--\eqref{fee} sobre el intervalo $\corchetes{t_{0} - \nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}, t_{0} + \nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}$, con la velocidad de deslizamiento $V$ aproximada por su valor en el centro de ese intervalo, $t_{0}$. Con esta aproximaci\'on, las ecuaciones de la variable de estado se convierten en EDO lineales que pueden ser integradas anal\'iticamente.\

\vspace{0.3cm}
%Paso 4
    \textbf{Paso 4}: Integre la velocidad de deslizamiento $V$ de la ecuaci\'on~\eqref{VelDiscret} sobre el intervalo $\corchetes{t_{0}, t_{0} + \Delta t}$ y finalmente aproxime $\Psi$ por $\Psi ^{t_{0} + \nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}$. \
\vspace{0.3cm}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot for your knowledge!
[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: (cont'd) `\SetAlgoLined` and `\KwData` are, in fact not defined (at least with my preamble. You should complete your MWE

Comment: Hi, you're right. Here is yhe complete code. I would like to give more line spacing son the equations and text don't look tight and also justify the code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get justified text, you can use the `ragged2e` package and `\justifying`, to set the linespread, `\usepackage{setspace}` and something like `\setstretch{1.5}`.

To simplyfy the usage of all these commands, you can wrap it in a newcommand. (thanks [@gernot for the suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364773/justify-text-in-the-algorithm-enviroment/364783?noredirect=1#comment898555_364783)!)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\selectlanguage{spanish} 
\usepackage[spanish,onelanguage,ruled,vlined,fillcomment ]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsfonts}   % Para fuentes no comunes
\usepackage{amssymb}  % Para simbolos no comunes
\usepackage{amsmath}   % Algunas cosas matematicas
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage[]{units}
%Funciones
\def\sign{\mathop{\mbox{\normalfont sign}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\evf}[2]{\mathop{\big|_{#1}^{#2}\big.}\limits}
\newcommand{\bez}{\mathop{\mathbbm{b}}}
\newcommand{\ba}[1]{\overline{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ti}[1]{\tilde{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\h}[1]{\hat{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\entera}[1]{\left[\!\left[{#1}\right]\!\right]}
\newcommand{\encima}[1]{\overline{\;#1}}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\mid {#1}\mid}
\newcommand{\norma}[1]{\parallel {#1} \parallel}
\newcommand{\mbf}[1]{\mathbf{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\area}{\mathfrak{A}}
\newcommand{\parentesis}[1]{\left({#1}\right)}
\newcommand{\corchetes}[1]{\left[{#1}\right]}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}

\newcommand\Paso[1]{\medskip\par\noindent\textbf{Paso #1:}\ \justifying} 

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[h!] 
\caption{Esquema MOSN de integraci\'on trapezoidal en tiempo.}
\label{AlgoTrapezoidal}
\SetAlgoLined
\setstretch{1.5}
\vspace{0.3cm}
\KwData{Las velocidades en los NFD $\corchetes{v^{\pm}_{x}}^{t_{0}}_{i}$ son conocidas de c\'aculos previos.}\vspace{0.3cm} 
\KwResult{Integraci\'on temporal del sistema Velocidad--Estado.}

\Paso{1} Calcule $\corchetes{u^{\pm}_{x}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i}$ y $\corchetes{u^{*}_{z}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i+\nicefrac{1}{2}}$. Usando las velocidades en los NFD y condiciones iniciales, se obtiene la integraci\'on centrada $\corchetes{u^{\pm}_{x}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i} = \corchetes{u^{\pm}_{x}}^{t_{0}-\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i} + \Delta t \corchetes{v^{\pm}_{x}}^{t_{0}}_{i}$. Luego, calcule $\corchetes{u^{*}_{z}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i + \nicefrac{1}{2}}$ de la condici\'on de continuidad de $\tau_{zz}$ en el plano de falla. Esto es, sustituir la anterior aproximaci\'on de $\corchetes{\frac{\partial u^{\pm}_{x}}{\partial x}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i+\nicefrac{1}{2}}$ y la estimada de $\corchetes{\frac{\partial u^{\pm}_{z}}{\partial z}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i+\nicefrac{1}{2}}$ (usando est\'eciles en una direcci\'on de la matriz $\boldsymbol G$) en esta condici\'on de continuidad para obtener $\corchetes{u^{*}_{z}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i+\nicefrac{1}{2}}$.

\Paso{2} Obtener los esfuerzos $\corchetes{\tau^{\pm}_{xx}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i+\nicefrac{1}{2}}$ y $\corchetes{\tau^{\pm}_{zz}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i+\nicefrac{1}{2}}$ introduciendo $\corchetes{\frac{\partial u^{\pm}_{x}}{\partial x}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i+\nicefrac{1}{2}}$ y $\corchetes{\frac{\partial u^{\pm}_{z}}{\partial z}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i+\nicefrac{1}{2}}$ en la Ley de Hooke (ecuaciones~\ref{Hooke1}--\ref{Hooke3}), diferenciados para obtener el gradiente del esfuerzo en los NFD $\corchetes{\frac{\partial \tau^{\pm}_{xx}}{\partial x}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i}$, y usados en la ecuaic\'on~\eqref{Rest} para obtener $\corchetes{R^{\pm}}^{t_{0}+\nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}_{i}$.

\Paso{3} Con la velocidad y la variable de estado centro--distribu\'idas en tiempo como en la Figura~\eqref{IntTrapezoidal}, integre las ecuaciones de evoluci\'on de la variable de estado \eqref{feq}--\eqref{fee} sobre el intervalo $\corchetes{t_{0} - \nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}, t_{0} + \nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}$, con la velocidad de deslizamiento $V$ aproximada por su valor en el centro de ese intervalo, $t_{0}$. Con esta aproximaci\'on, las ecuaciones de la variable de estado se convierten en EDO lineales que pueden ser integradas anal\'iticamente.

\Paso{4} Integre la velocidad de deslizamiento $V$ de la ecuaci\'on~\eqref{VelDiscret} sobre el intervalo $\corchetes{t_{0}, t_{0} + \Delta t}$ y finalmente aproxime $\Psi$ por $\Psi ^{t_{0} + \nicefrac{\Delta t}{2}}$. 
\vspace{0.3cm}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It might help to defined something like `\newcommand\Paso[1]{\medskip\par\noindent\textbf{Paso #1:}\ \justifying}` to get a uniform layout. And to remove the single backslashes at the end of the paragraphs. Then you can start each step by just writing `\Paso{1} ... \Paso{2} ...` and can remove all the `\vskip`, `\noindent`, `\justifying` stuff.

Comment: Hi, this effectively solve my problem. But see that steps 2, 3 and 4 in the Algorithm are tabbed. I just solve this new issue by writing \noindent before \textbf{Paso X}. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help on this. :)

Comment: @gernot I've tried with your \newcommand but it set the whole text aligned to the left. Sorry :/

Comment: @AdN (1) Take Sam's code. (2) Add the definition `\newcommand\Paso[1]...` (see above) to the preamble.  (3) Replace `Velocidad--Estado.}
\vspace{0.3cm}
%Paso 1
\textbf{Paso 1}: \justifying ` by `Velocidad--Estado.} \Paso{1}`. (4) Replace `\nicefrac{1}{2}}$.

\vspace{0.3cm}
%Paso 2
\noindent \textbf{Paso 2}: \justifying` by `\nicefrac{1}{2}}$. \Paso{2}` (5) ... and so on. (The line breaks get lost in the comment here, you can add one before `\Paso`) The formatting stays the same, but you don't have all these formatting commands distributed among the text.

Comment: @gernot Thanks for your suggestion! I included it in my answer.